# Differences that matter between GTK+ and QT?

Tags: user-interface, qt, gtk

### What are the finer differences between QT and GTK+?

Specifically I need to know the finer differences.
Language neutral, Windows/Linux neutral. Just the finer points please...

1. **How *native* are the widgets / controls to the window manger, from its standpoint?** Example: If it were a text control, would it process: a WM_COMMAND or EM_SETSEL message sent to it? If not, how do third-party applications / screen readers interact with the control / widget?
2. **Advanced widgets available in one toolkit and not available in the other?** Add-Ons are fine to describe.
3. **What is the quality of theming from a *multimedia / special effects* standpoint?** like powerpoint style special effects such as fade-ins of widgets/docks. What's the ease of coding for these scenarios?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**: I'm probably biased towards Qt as I never used GTK seriously.

- Qt's graphics view and scene system is awesome, GTK only has low level Cairo.
- Writing custom widgets seems easier with Qt, probably because of the OO design. I don't know which API has more "advanced" widgets, but the basic ones are probably enough for most applications with a little bit of customization.
- If you want a completely custom display for your app with special effects and all, you can easily write one based on graphics view/scene. Qt 4.7 also adds [Qt Quick](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtquick.html) to design fancy interfaces, I didn't have the opportunity to test it yet but it looks pretty cool.

Overall I think both are great frameworks and offer enough for any application, but with Qt you get everything in a nice package, when you have to use 3rd party additions or reinvent the wheel to get the same job done with GTK.

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer because it is the best one currently.

Answer (score 3):

Although you didn't ask this, it's worth pointing out the different philosophies between Qt and Gtk+ (or Gtkmm, the C++ version of Gtk+).

Qt is a full application development toolkit. It includes XML parsers, concurrency framework and so on. Gtkmm is **not**. From the gtkmm documentation:

> gtkmm is a GUI toolkit and nothing
>   more, and it strives to be the best
>   C++ GUI toolkit. That mandate does not
>   cover generic C++ data structures, an
>   XML parser, or database access.

The probably more fair comparison is between Qt and Gtkmm + a set of GNOME libraries.

For advanced widgets the GNOME libraries are really nice - take libgoffice, for example. But it doesn't have a beginner friendly documentation and you will end up having to ask questions in the mailing lists or the IRC channels. Qt is also very nice and have a much friendly documentation. The quality and availability are equivalent, in my opinion, but Qt usually have more documentation or, at least, is documented in a way more friendly to "outsiders".

Both have high quality presentation and effects. No meaningful difference. I like the Gtk+ appearance more than Qt, but it just a matter of personal taste.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the difference in philosophies. that right there should narrow down all the other answers to just gui..

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but:

- I find it really difficult to
  customize widgets in Gtk+, e.g. I
  want the behavior of widget X, but
  need to tweak the look beyond the
  usual style settings.
- OTOH I don't  like Qt's `moc`, but that's more of a
  personal thing.
- I'd also strongly
  recommend Gtkmm (the C++ wrapper)
  over plain Gtk+.

Comment: is moc apply to python? or is it language specific? I am using python

Comment: I have only experience with the C/C++ cores. But AFAICS the complete signal/slot stuff is done by the python binding, i.e. no extra tool needed.

Comment: Yup its all native in python, no moc stuff i.e widget.connect(some_func)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this bias to qt and shallow

- Qt has many eyecandy effect ( dont know about gtkmm).
- Qt has Qtconcurrent, higher level api for multithreading. probably more readable
  than Qthread Qmutex blablabla...
- Based from your question  I think you want to integrate desktop app to www,
  so just compare for yourself between **qtwebkit** , **gtkhtml** and **gtkwebkit** which one is likely to fit you better.

Answer (score 0):

I've narrowed it down to **XULRunner** or **GTK+**.

Here's why:

- I need to quickly become familiar with the internals. QT makes this difficult for me with so much on their ease-of-use solutions.
- QT is HUGE! I stopped a custom compile after it had been running for over 4hrs on my 3Ghz P4! *to be fair, QT provides many precompiled binaries*
- Out of the box themes for QT are rather too 'professional' looking. I need something cool, GTK+ has some neat themes which I can modify.
- I don't need / want to use the framework for networking, file management, multimedia, webkit, or anything *besides* a GUI frontend to other apps.

Note that the license in Qt is LGPL which is not good enough for many commercial projects. Same for GTK+, but at least you can *pay* for legally using Qt in commercial projects.

Comment: Qt is also very modular, I don't think the file size and compilation time are relevant points.

Comment: Was your mammoth compile using default configuration?  QtWebKit in particular takes a *long* time to compile, so if you don't need it, specify -no-webkit.  Also, debug binaries can (under some toolchains) be much larger and therefore cause lots of paging during the linking phase: specifying -release means that you only get release binaries.

Comment: The biggest reason I dislike QT is that the internals are not well documented. I am going to be doing some funky things using multiple frameworks (including XULRunner). Screwing with compile options was not worth the effort.

Comment: if your design depends on knowing the internals of a library, then your design isn't well thought out. The reason I say this is that internals can change at any time while documented interfaces tend to be stable. If you depend on knowledge of the inner workings of a library, then you are inviting breakage if the library is updated.

Comment: @Evan Teran, if all libraries used are well designed. However, this is not usually the case, and it is useful to know what goes on under the hood. Especially when a project uses multiple frameworks that have overlapping functionality.